# Code blocks don't show leading spaces in IE 9 (and 10)

Tags: support, code-formatting, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

Why doesn't a code block preserve whitespace in this PowerShell script? In the editor (using 4 spaces for the code block, and more spaces to indent) this looks like:

[image: Screen capture of code block in editor]

But I am not seeing any indentation whatsoever in IE9 (and neither in IE10/Win8 CP):

[image: Screen capture of Markdown code block in IE9]

And here's what you're seeing:

```
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)
$sitelists =  foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) 
{
    if ($web -eq "Search")
    {
        Write-Host "Come in"    
    }
}
```

Frankly I've gone to using `<pre></pre>` tags which can't be the right the way to do this but at least the results are readable - for now:

[image: Screen capture of pre formatted text in IE9]

And again, here's what you're seeing:

```
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)
$sitelists =  foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) 
{
    if ($web -eq "Search")
    {
        Write-Host "Come in"    
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use tabs...

Comment: OK, removed the tabs -replaced with 4 spaces and it still looks isn't preserving the indentation.

Comment: FWIW the code in the tagged PowerShell questions/answers used to look right but then sometime 6-9 months ago they started formatting like crap er with no indentation.  AFAICT this isn't a tab vs space problem.  This issue is **seriously** affecting the readability of PowerShell script on this forum.  So downvote this question all you want but there **is** a problem for us PowerShellers.  I guess there's always http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/threads.  The PowerShell script formatting seems to work pretty well there.

Comment: Keith, what differences do you see? Your two code examples look **identical** to me (Chrome 17, Windows 7), and both look identical to the raw editor text.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta - thanks for the constructive question.  :-)  I attached image that shows what I'm seeing in IE9/IE10.

Comment: I'm think I know what's going on.  A while back I had enable "Compatibility View" on IE9 because the text editor didn't work very well.  It seems if I disable that feature, it renders correctly and at this point the text editor seems to be working fine.  Sorry for the false alarm folks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If anybody else runs into this with Internet Explorer 9/10 make sure you don't have "Compatibility View" (the broken page icon in the address bar) enabled for the site:

[image: Compatibility mode icon in IE]

Comment: BTW, according to Microsoft:

"If Internet Explorer recognizes that the webpage isn't compatible, you'll see the Compatibility View button on the Address bar."

I wonder why SO isn't recognized as compatible?

Comment: And anther oddity: the first screen capture does preserve the double spaces in `=  foreach`.

Comment: And what about Firefox 16.0.2 (win 7 x64)? It's the such problem too.