# Formatting oddities on stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code blocks don't show leading spaces in IE 9 (and 10)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127693/code-blocks-dont-show-leading-spaces-in-ie-9-and-10)

I'm noticing some formatting anomalies this morning. I'm running Win7, IE8, cold boot, first noticed on the site about 1 hour ago.

First, quoting code appears to trim leading spaces; I cannot indent as would be apprpriate. This behavior is happening when I a.) use the {} button in the browser-based editor, b.) manually key spaces in front of the lines, or c.) use ` to delineate code from text

Example:

```
 public class foo()
 {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
      } 
 }
```

[image: Screenshot of indents]

Second, tag buttons appear to be setting to a default size rather than dynamically sizing to the width of the button text.

[image: Screenshot of tags]

Comment: Did you use tabs for indentation?

Comment: Empty your cache.

Comment: Make sure the spaces are the ordinary space character, not some fancy character added by some IDE or when using certain cultures having double space character..

Comment: That screenshot of the tags looks like your IE8 is running in compatibility mode (which essentially turns it into an IE7, which we don't support anymore). Check if that's the case, and if so, see if turning off compat mode fixes your issues.

Comment: @DanielFischer: spaces from spacebar, or automagically formatted via ` or clicking on the {} button. @BoltClock, cache is emptied every logon by corporate IT scripting. @balpha...I think you're right on the money. We do have some machines in the company still running IE7; likely they've got the IE8 users dumbed down to the lowest common denominator. At any rate, it sounds like an issue on my end...just wanted to make sure it wasn't the site. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use IE8 to access stackoverflow, and the tag issue happens a lot with compatibility mode. I've never seen it happen outside of compatibility mode, and I'm not sure, but I think it might always happen in compatibility mode.

Considering the strange things that happen in compatibility mode (and how eagerly IE8 sometimes jumps into it), I'd say that's your problem.