# Code indenting just appears to be broken here

Tags: bug, code-formatting, indentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code blocks don’t show leading spaces in IE 9 (and 10)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127693/code-blocks-dont-show-leading-spaces-in-ie-9-and-10)

I was trying to edit this person's post. All the spacing is there but it is ignoring all my spaces and indenting. Try editing the post and see what I am doing wrong because all the spaces are there and they are spaces, not tabs.

[is this code making sense at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135929/is-this-code-making-sense-at-all)

Incidentally, I would classify this as a bug, even if there is a workaround solution or a reason behind it, because your standard stackoverflow.com poster would expect it to work with the way I posted it, and therefore it should. Something from my experience as a developer of software. They will probably not come here searching for a solution.

Comment: Can't see any problem there. Are you sure you used ordinary blank space and not some fancy character that just looks like a space?

Comment: No repro here either...can you still reproduce the issue? Can you post screenshots?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem either.

Comment: I get this behaviour in IE8 with `Browser Mode: IE8 Compat View` and `Document Mode: IE7 Standards` which is, for some reason, the page default.

Comment: The actual example was edited. I am using IE8 here, unfortunately what they force us to use at work.